# Unable to launch Unity Tweak Tool

Tags: unity, 14.10

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu, to the 14.10 version.
To fix some problems with the graphic environment, I launched unity-tweak-tool and... It didn't work at all! If I start the program from the command line prompt, I've got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 72, in 
>      UnityTweakTool.Application()
>    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/**init**.py", line 79, in **init**
>      executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Even after removing & reinstalling Unity Tweak Tool I got this error. I'd like to know how to fix it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, I am running 14.04 instead of 14.10, but here's what worked for me:

You need to open the file shown in the crash dump, (if using Vim, type ":set nu" without quotes to get line numbers) and go to line 79, and you will see:

```
 executable_name=cmd_old.split('\x00')[1]
```

You want to change that 1 to a zero.

Then relaunch.

Again, this works for me on 14.04, but your results may vary.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same exact problem a few days ago.

I ran bleachbit and cleared the system cache.

This corrected the problem.

Hope it helps!